# AWS SQSClient GetQueueUrlAsync is throwing "Error Unmarshalling response back from AWS"

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sqs-fifo

I have a simple AWS SQS service method in .net standard2.0 project where I am calling SQSClient.GetQueueUrlAsync() to get the queue URL. Suddenly, it started throwing an "Error unmarshalling response back from AWS." In the inner exception, it says "invalid character '<' in input string."
I have no idea why I'm getting this error. Has anyone encountered this type of error and knows the fix? I would greatly appreciate it.
I am testing it using LocalStack.

Restarted the localstack
Deleted and created the queue

Comment: You are sending a HTTP Request from client to server and then server is sending an HTTP Response from server back to client.  The Request and Client have a HTTP Header Content-Type which is the type of data in the Request/Response Body.  There is something wrong with the Content-Type not matching the data in the body.  The angle bracket is usually associated with XML data.  JSON data doesn't usually contain the angle bracket.  Did code every work?  What changes did you make when error started to occur?

Comment: "Error Unmarshalling Response" means the data in the response did not deserialize because the wrong type of deserializer was used.  So the Content-Type is wrong.

Comment: It was working fine. My code is just calling the GetQueueUrlAsync(queueName) of SQS client which returns object of GetQueueUrlResponse type.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/MSQSISQSGetQueueUrlAsyncGetQueueUrlRequestCancellationTokenNET45.html

Comment: The page you are referencing is Net 4.5.  What is you current target?  Did you change the target since it last worked?  What version AWS SQS are you using?  It may be a bug that existed in old library that is now fixed.  The latest version of AWS SQS is three.  Read second line at following page about versions : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

Comment: This issue probably is due to version of libraries changing.  Or the data is different from when code was working.  The angle bracket in the data may not be valid.  Did data change?